# Use Image classification model trained with coco

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

i need to work with an image classification trained with the dataset named coco. I searched on internet but i only find objects detectors.

Anyone know pre-trained models image classification for tensorflow 2?

Comment: Couldn't find `Coco` as these are coco dataset is for `object detection`, but pre-trained models on top of `ILSVRC-2012-CLS` - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim

Comment: Another question, i need an object detection and a image classificator trainet with the same dataset. Due to the image classification is trained with ILSVRC-2012-CLS, its possible to train an object detection with these dataset?

Comment: Object Detection is different from Image Classification read the first part of this answer for more info.https://stackoverflow.com/a/64956657/5801823. However you can train a classifier model and detection model. You just have to extract the boxes from the training dataset yourself to train the classifier. eg. coco dataset boxes as images

Answer (score 1):

Object Detection is different from Image Classification.

> Object Detection algorithms act as a combination of image classification and object localization. It takes an image as input and produces one or more bounding boxes with the class label attached to each bounding box. These algorithms are capable enough to deal with multi-class classification and localization as well as to deal with the objects with multiple occurrences. [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64956657/5801823)

You can however use the coco dataset to strip out each and every localisation box and create a new dataset which can now be fed for your image classifier. You will have to do processing of the coco dataset to achieve this.

For eg. If your dataset annotations looks like this: (contains 4 objects localised namely the following):

1. 123, 23, 13, 45, kite, image_1.jpg
2. 133, 43, 213, 77, bird image_1.jpg
3. 133, 13, 413, 73, bird, image_2.jpg
4. 12, 233, 440, 34, tree, image_1.jpg

You can write a script to convert into this:

1. kite_123231345image_1.jpg
2. bird_1334521377image_1.jpg
3. bird_1331341373image_2.jpg
4. tree_1223344034image_1.jpg

and create those images with cut out boxes.

And use this annotation to train your classifier. I have personally done this on cocodataset before and gives decent precision.

Comment: and how many time can take train a model with all the clases of coco?

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Also don't forget to upvote if my answer helped you. Thanks

Comment: If i want to train an image classifier model with coco dataset, how many time can take the train ?

Comment: It will depend upon your own machine and how you run it for. This is purely based on your system and environment.